# Informatica Transaction Control Transformation Error

Tags: informatica

I am using Transaction control for all load plans in the mapping. It still throws an error: "The Target Definition has more than one Transaction Control point connected to it stackoverflow informatica". Any idea why this error?

Thank you

Comment: Try removing the Transacrion Control transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this happens when you have below scenario

```
Src1 - SQ1- EXP1- TGT1
Src2 - SQ2- Exp2-TC-TGT2
```

**Solution:**
You need to define Transaction Control transformation in other pipeline with property `TC_CONTINUE_TRANSATION`.

I mean make it like-

```
Src1 - SQ1- EXP1-TC(TC_CONTINUE_TRANSATION)- TGT1
Src2 - SQ2- Exp2-TC-TGT2
```